# Computation of conditionseries of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am studying Riemann rearrangement theorem. and I stuck at the computation of this:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{4n-2}-\frac{1}{4n})  $

How to simplify to get the sum ?

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{4n-2}=\frac{1}{4n-2}$, so you are left with $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\frac{1}{2}\log 2.$$

Comment: Nice and precise. Thank you so much

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Could you please explain, why the first series equals the second? Just interesting to understand that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio Can you please suggest me how to solve this types of problems ? I mean do you have any material or resources to share with me ?